# setEnabled:NO doesn't work for iOS button

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a UIButton that I am trying to disable when its action fires.  This has no effect:

```
[self.controlBTN setEnabled:NO];
```

Just to ward off the inevitable question, self.controlBTN really does point to the button in question.  I offer as proof the fact that if I replace it with this statement:

```
[self.controlBTN setTitle:@"What?" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

the title changes.  So, I can change the title, but I can't disable the button.  Why?  The docs say enabled is a property, and don't mention it being read-only.

Comment: What do you mean by disable? Do you want the button to be hidden or only unclickable?

Comment: Are you sure you connect the button from the storyboard with the property? if not thats why.

Comment: What do you mean by "when its action fires"? Are you trying to disable it after it fires? Where do you have that code?

Comment: Post some context and some code as to where this button is being created. Is it, for example, being created on a tableview? setEnabled works, so if it's not working in your case, it could be the way your button is set up.

Comment: Are you testing by the look of the button or if it calls the action method again? Is another part of your code enabling the button again? The property does work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[UIButton setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled]` will work without any issues. You're either setting it back to `YES` somehow, or you're probably re-allocating the button and adding it back as a subview over the older button (by using the same frame).

Such mistakes happen more often than you think, especially when the button is placed on a `UITableViewCell`.

You haven't posted the code for where you're creating the button, so I can provide you a speculative answer at best. If you post more code, I may be able to provide you with a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, folks... What I failed to mention is that I was trying to reenable the UIButton after a delay, using dispatch_after().  Unfortunately, this statement:

dispatch_after(2*NSEC_PER_SEC,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{[sender setEnabled:YES];});

was executing instantaneously, so it appeared as if setEnabled: wasn't working.

I now have more carefully read the documentation for the *when* parameter, replacing the 2*NSEC_PER_SEC with dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,2*NSEC_PER_SEC) and everything is working as it should.

Mea culpa.

Comment: So basically, you were setting it back to YES somehow... :)

Comment: Yes, Sid, you are correct (and I marked your reply accordingly... I was indeed setting it back).  Thanks for your help!